# Saving dictionary of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a DB with a couple of years worth of site data. I am now attempting to use that data for analytics - plotting and sorting of advertising costs by keyword, etc.

One of the data grabs from the DB takes minutes to complete. While I could spend some time optimizing the SQL statements I use to get the data I'd prefer to simply leave that class and it's SQL alone, grab the data, and save the results to a data file for faster retrieval later. Most of this DB data isn't going to change so I could write a separate python script to update the file every 24 hours and then use that file for this long running task.

The data is being returned as a dictionary of numpy arrays. When I use `numpy.save('data', data)` the file is saved just fine. When I use `data2 = numpy.load('data.npy')` it loads the file without error. However, the output `data2` doesn't not equal the original `data`.

Specifically the line `data == data2` returns false. Additionally, if I use the following:

```
for key, key_data in data.items():
  print key
```

it works. But when I replace `data.items()` with `data2.items()` then I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Using `type(data)` I get `dict`. Using `type(data2)` I get `numpy.ndarray`.

So how do I fix this? I want the loaded data to equal the data I passed in for saving. Is there an argument to numpy.save to fix this or do I need some form of simple reformatting function to reformat the loaded data into the proper structure?

Attempts to get into the `ndarray` via for loops or indexing all lead to errors about indexing a 0-d array. Casting like this `dict(data2)` also fails for iterating over a 0-d array. However, Spyder shows value of the array and it includes the data I saved. I just can't figure out how to get to it.

If I need to reformat the loaded data I'd appreciate some example code on how to do this.

Comment: Note to future self:  `np.savez('arrs', **my_dict)` is simpler to use than `np.save(my_dict)` for a flat dict of arrays, because the result of `np.load('arrs.npz')` can be directly indexed like a Python dict.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Let's look at a small example:

```
In [819]: N
Out[819]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.]])

In [820]: data={'N':N}

In [821]: np.save('temp.npy',data)

In [822]: data2=np.load('temp.npy')

In [823]: data2
Out[823]: 
array({'N': array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.]])}, dtype=object)
```

`np.save` is designed to save numpy arrays.  `data` is a dictionary.  So it wrapped it in a object array, and used `pickle` to save that object.  Your `data2` probably has the same character.

You get at the array with:

```
In [826]: data2[()]['N']
Out[826]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.]])
```

Comment: Would never have occurred to me to use `[()]`. I don't think I've ever seen an index like that in any other language I've used.

Comment: If you only save a dictionary of arrays, and numpy.save uses pickle anyways, you might as well use pickle directly?

Comment: `np.save` is the most direct and compact way to save an array.  For a dictionary of arrays, I'd prefer `np.savez`.  For a dictionary, which might have stuff besides arrays, `np.save` as used here, or `pickle` are probably equivalent.  Funny thing is, I'm having trouble running `pickle` (without reading the docs) to make a comparison.

Comment: Indexing takes a tuple, one value for each dimension of the array.  For a 0d array that means you can index with a empty tuple.  It works just like `[(1,2)]`, `[1,2]`, just for 0d arrays.

Comment: instead of the weird `[()]` notation (which corresponds to indexing with an empty tuple, I guess), numpy offers a method that does exactly the same thing: `item`.

Comment: `item` is narrower in meaning and application. Here with a single element array they do the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

When saving a dictionary with numpy, the dictionary is encoded into an array.
To have what you need, you can do as in this example:

```
my_dict = {'a' : np.array(range(3)), 'b': np.array(range(4))}

np.save('my_dict.npy',  my_dict)    

my_dict_back = np.load('my_dict.npy')

print(my_dict_back.item().keys())    
print(my_dict_back.item().get('a'))
```

So you are probably missing **`.item()`** for the reloaded dictionary.
Check this out:

```
for key, key_d in data2.item().items():
    print key, key_d
```

The comparison `my_dict == my_dict_back.item()` works only for dictionaries that does not have lists or arrays in their values.

---

EDIT: for the `item()` issue mentioned above, I think it is a better option to save dictionaries with the library `pickle` rather than with `numpy`.

---

SECOND EDIT: if not happy with pickle, and all the types in the dictionary are compatible with , `json` is an option as well.

Answer (score 7):

I really liked the [`deepdish`](http://deepdish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html) (it saves them in `HDF5` format):

```
>>> import deepdish as dd
>>> d = {'foo': np.arange(10), 'bar': np.ones((5, 4, 3))}
>>> dd.io.save('test.h5', d)

$ ddls test.h5
/bar                       array (5, 4, 3) [float64]
/foo                       array (10,) [int64]

>>> d = dd.io.load('test.h5')
```

for my experience, it seems to be partially broken for large datasets, though :(

Comment: In which way is it broken for large datasets?

Comment: I encountered some issues with saving extremely large lists of objects