# How to serialize an array in python using pickle?

Tags: python

Hello I have a problem when I tried to serialize an array with python,
I have the dictionary

```
d={}
d['data']= [array([2, 5, 3], dtype=uint8), array([4, 1, 9], dtype=uint8)]
```

but my error is:

```
'array' is not defined
```

so, I have 2 questions:

1.- how can I do an array like:

```
array([2, 5, 3],[4, 1, 9], dtype=uint8)
```

to create the array I use

```
append()
```

and how can I serialize the dictionary with the form of the array(question 1) using the next function

```
with open('outp', 'wb') as fo:
   pickle.dump(d, fo, 2)
```

If I remove the words 'array' and 'dtype=uint8' it has no errors, but I think that is not the correct form to serialize an array
Thanks

Comment: `from numpy import array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I remove the words 'array' and 'dtype=uint8' it has no errors

This is beacause without these words then you are simply creating a list which can be dumped by pickle indeed.

However the `array` you are mentionning seems like a numpy array, you can simply add `from numpy import array`in the beginning of your script.

Also, you can not make this `array([2, 5, 3],[4, 1, 9])` because a 2 dimensional array with numpy is created like this : `array([[2, 5, 3],[4, 1, 9]])`

then once you have your array you can dump it like this:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
d={}
d['data']= [np.array([2, 5, 3], dtype=np.int8), np.array([4, 1, 9], dtype=np.int8)]
with open('outp', 'wb') as fo:
    pickle.dump(d, fo, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) According to the Numpy docs, there is a builtin method for that. Check [ndarray.dump](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dump.html).

2) According to [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811918/saving-dictionary-of-numpy-arrays) you can wrap the dictionary in an object and save it.