# What is the meaning of `numpy.array(value)`?

Tags: numpy

`numpy.array(value)` evaluates to true, if value is `int`, `float` or `complex`. The result seems to be a shapeless array (`numpy.array(value).shape` returns `()`).

Reshaping the above like so `numpy.array(value).reshape(1)` works fine and `numpy.array(value).reshape(1).squeeze()` reverses this and again results in a shapeless array.

What is the rationale behind this behavior? Which use-cases exist for this behaviour?

Comment: You get a scalar from a scalar. What's *not* rational about that?

Comment: Also, the call to squeeze is missing parens

Comment: You can pass `ndmin=1` if you don't want to get a scalar.

Comment: The way I understand it, a scalar is not an array. But `type(np.array(11))` is `numpy.ndarray`. My issue is not that I do not understand what a scalar is or what an array is but that numpy gives a scalar the type array.

Comment: It's a 0D array, not shape-less, the shape is the zero-length tuple `()`. There is nothing illogical about it. It is also quite useful for example if you are writing a function that you want to be able to process arrays and scalars alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a zero-dimensional array like `np.array(3)`, you get an object that behaves as an array in 99.99% of situations. You can inspect the basic properties:

```
>>> x = np.array(3)
>>> x
array(3)
>>> x.ndim
0
>>> x.shape
()
>>> x[None]
array([3])
>>> type(x)
numpy.ndarray
>>> x.dtype
dtype('int32')
```

So far so good. The logic behind this is simple: you can process any array-like object the same way, regardless of whether is it a number, list or array, just by wrapping it in a call to `np.array`.

One thing to keep in mind is that when you index an array, the index tuple must have `ndim` or fewer elements. So you can't do:

```
>>> x[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Instead, you have to use a zero-sized tuple (since `x[]` is invalid syntax):

```
>>> x[()]
3
```

You can also  use the array as a scalar instead:

```
>>> y = x + 3
>>> y
6
>>> type(y)
numpy.int32
```

Adding two scalars produces a scalar instance of the `dtype`, not another array. That being said, you can use `y` from this example in exactly the same way you would `x`, 99.99% of the time, since dtypes inherit from `ndarray`. It does not matter that `3` is a Python `int`, since `np.add` will wrap it in an `array` regardless. `y = x + x` will yield identical results.

One difference between `x` and `y` in these examples is that `x` is *not* officially considered to be a scalar:

```
>>> np.isscalar(x)
False
>>> np.isscalar(y)
True
```

The indexing issue can potentially throw a monkey wrench in your plans to index any array like-object. You can easily get around it by supplying `ndmin=1` as an argument to the constructor, or using a `reshape`:

```
>>> x1 = np.array(3, ndmin=1)
>>> x1
array([3])

>>> x2 = np.array(3).reshape(-1)
>>> x2
array([3])
```

I generally recommend the former method, as it requires no prior knowledge of the dimensionality of the input.

**FurtherRreading:**

- [Why are 0d arrays in Numpy not considered scalar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/773030/2988730)

Comment: `x[()]` - you can always index with a `ndim` tuple.

Comment: @hpaulj. Thanks for the tip. I updated the language.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and the link to the further reading. This made for an educational evening.

Comment: I just stumbled upon another way to get the value of a scalar out of a numpy array with the [`item`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html#numpy.ndarray.item) function: `x.item()`. Inspiration came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45661259) when researching how to work with `numpy.savez()`